# Adding a repository to apt-mirror

Tags: ubuntu, repository, apt-mirror

I set up apt-mirror with the following config:

```
      GNU nano 2.5.3                                                                          File: /etc/apt/mirror.list

############# config ##################
#
# set base_path    /var/spool/apt-mirror
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org xenial kms6

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

However, I cannot seem to be able to mirror ubuntu.kurento.org

Whenever I do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
```

I get the following messages:

> E: Unable to locate package kurento-media-server-6.0 E: Couldn't find
>   any package by glob 'kurento-media-server-6.0' E: Couldn't find any
>   package by regex 'kurento-media-server-6.0'

On the client machine I am connecting to my local mirror and I am able to get updates etc but not for kurento package. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Your other configuration lines have `deb-amd64` or `deb-i386` for other repositories, does kurento repository line have only `deb` on purpose?

Answer (score -1):

Please set path at set base_path and also uncomment it.

Comment: (1) Why would it be helpful to set `base_path` when it’s not used anywhere (that’s not commented out)? (2) You say *(something)* “*and **also*** uncomment [`base_path`].” What does the first part of your answer mean? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.